# Calling methods common to types in a boost::variant

Tags: c++, generic-programming, visitor-pattern, boost-variant

If all the types in my `boost::variant` support the same method, is there a way to call it generically (i.e. not calling it seperately for each method of the `static_visitor`)?

I'm trying to get something like this to work:

```
class A
{
    void boo() {}
};

class B
{
    void boo() {}
};

class C
{
    void boo() {}
};

typedef boost::variant<A, B, C> X;

void foo(X& d)
{
    x.boo();
}
```

but it fails to compile saying `'boo' : is not a member of 'boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2>'`.

Currently, I have some classes all inherit from an interface so that their single shared method can be used polymorphically.  I also want to be able to use the classes via a visitor as all other methods are unique to each concrete class.  I was hoping `boost::variant` might be a better alternative to implementing my own visitor mechanism here.  Is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no direct way, but you can make the static_visitor pretty concise using templating.

Modified from the boost docs:

```
struct boo_generic : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()( T & operand ) const
    {
        operand.boo();
    }
};
```

Now you can do this:

```
boost::apply_visitor( boo_generic(), v );
```

Infact you can generalise this to take a function pointer of your base class:

```
struct fn_generic : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
   fn_generic( void (IBase::fn)() ) : fn_(fn) {}
   template<T> void operator() ( T & op ) const { op.*fn(); }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
boost::apply_visitor( boo_generic( IBase::boo ), v );
```

Or something like that - I've probably got my function pointer syntax wrong, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Base {
    virtual void boo() = 0;
};

class A : Base
{
    void boo() override {}
};

class B : Base
{
    void boo() override {}
};

class C : Base
{
    void boo() override {}
};

typedef boost::variant<A, B, C> X;

void foo(X& x)
{
    boost::relaxed_get<Base>(x).boo();
}
```

Won't `boost::relaxed_get` work in the example above? 
Note: this required Real Time Type Information (RTTI) support.